# Script Builds but script Returned a Failure Result - System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ssis

I have copied the code from http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/03/how-to-load-text-csv-files-with-same-or.html however the code in the link is using SQL Server. I am trying to move this over to MySQL but I am hitting error messages.

The have changed the namescape to reference MySQL instead of SQL Server I believe and the script builds with no errors. When I try and run the code it kicks up the error messages below:

Inside the SSIS I have a connection via an ADO.net destination table using a connection manager called "DB_Conn_IBDRStagingDev". The connection is appears to be working. I feel this is really close but I am just not clear what is creating the errors. Any help would be wonderful.

Thanks,

David

```
Errors: 

System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ST_e8360d01864e4c2c9dd30a3739a60370.ScriptMain.Main()

Code: 

    #region Namespaces
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    #endregion
    
    namespace ST_e8360d01864e4c2c9dd30a3739a60370
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            try
            {

                //Declare Variables
                string SourceFolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolder"].Value.ToString();
                string FileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString();
                string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["User::FileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
                string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationTable"].Value.ToString();
                string ArchiveFolder = Dts.Variables["User::ArchiveFolder"].Value.ToString();
                string Database = Dts.Variables["User::Database"].Value.ToString();
                //string ColumnList = "";

                //Reading file names one by one
                string SourceDirectory = SourceFolderPath;
                string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory, "*" + FileExtension);
                foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
                {

                  
                    MySqlConnection myADONETConnection = new MySqlConnection();
                    myADONETConnection = (MySqlConnection)
                    (Dts.Connections["DB_Conn_IBDRStagingDev"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as MySqlConnection);

                    //Writing Data of File Into Table
                    int counter = 0;
                    string line;
                    string ColumnList = "";
                    //MessageBox.Show(fileName);

                    System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile =
                    new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                    while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (counter == 0)
                        {
                            ColumnList = "`" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "`,`") + "`";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string query = "Insert into " + TableName + " (" + ColumnList + ") ";
                            query += "VALUES('" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "','") + "')";

                            // MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());
                            MySqlCommand myCommand1 = new MySqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
                            myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        counter++;
                    }

                    SourceFile.Close();
                    //move the file to archive folder after adding datetime to it
                    File.Move(fileName, ArchiveFolder + "\\" +
                        (fileName.Replace(SourceFolderPath, "")).Replace(FileExtension, "")
                        + "_" + datetime + FileExtension);
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // Create Log File for Errors
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::LogFolder"].Value.ToString()
                    + "\\" + "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }

            }


        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception message identifies the problem: `Connection must be valid and open.`

Before your code calls `MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`, it must first call `MySqlConnection.Open`.

Secondly, you don't need to create a `new MySqlConnection` that you don't use.

Change:

```cs
MySqlConnection myADONETConnection = new MySqlConnection();
myADONETConnection = (MySqlConnection)
                    (Dts.Connections["DB_Conn_IBDRStagingDev"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as MySqlConnection);
```

to:

```cs
using (var myADONETConnection = (MySqlConnection) Dts.Connections["DB_Conn_IBDRStagingDev"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction))
{
    // ...
}
```

You must use the `using` declaration to ensure that the connection is closed and cleaned up when you've finished using it.

Finally, if you have a CSV file, you can load it directly by using `MySqlBulkLoader`, which will handle all the CSV parsing for you. This should be a lot simpler than reading the file line-by-line and building `INSERT` statements.